# Dynamically shift left OR right

Tags: c

I have a pretty simple question. Is there a way to dynamically shift bitwise to the left OR to the right, e.g. depending on the sign of an int.

```
signed int n = 3;
signed int m = -2;

int number1 = 8;
int number2 = 8;

//number1 shift n;
//number2 shift m;
```

In this case I want to shift number1 3 bits to the left and number2 2 bits to the right. Is there a way without `if else`?

Comment: You should only shift unsigned ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `?:` count as an `if-else` ?

```
int x = (n > 0) ? (number1 << n) : (number1 >> (-n));
int y = (m > 0) ? (number2 << n) : (number2 >> (-m));
```

Comment: '?:' does count as 'if-else' but I find this answer satisfying for my needs, as it is short and reliable. This doesn't mean, that the other answers aren't correct. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

For 32 bit:

x = (((long long)x) << 32) >> (32 - n)

Comment: I like the elegance of this approach, but this also has to work for 64 bit integers and would cause to many overflows.

Comment: For 64 bit: `(__int128)x << 64 >> (64 - n)`. Only works with compilers with __int128 support (gcc, clang). You can dynamically determine the length in bits with `CHAR_BIT*sizeof x` but it's much harder to get the type to cast dynamically

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned (*fx_t)(unsigned, int);

unsigned shiftleft(unsigned val, int bits) {
  return val << bits;
}

unsigned shiftright(unsigned val, int bits) {
  return val >> (-bits);
}

unsigned shift(unsigned val, int bits) {
  static fx_t sshift[2] = {shiftright, shiftleft};
  return sshift[bits >= 0](val, bits);
}

int main(void) {
  signed int n = 3;
  signed int m = -2;
  unsigned number1 = 8;
  unsigned number2 = 8;

  printf("%u\n", shift(number1, n));
  printf("%u\n", shift(number2, m));

  return 0;
}
```

You can "see the code running" at ideone: <s>http://ideone.com/F2vAB</s> http://ideone.com/x1RbQ

Comment: The `shiftright` and `shiftleft` should be defined with `static`, but I don't want to edit the answer and get it out of synch with ideone.

Comment: That's still using a conditional (`bits >= 0`), so there's a hidden  `if` in there.

Comment: you can use `-(bits >> (CHAR_BIT*sizeof bits - 1))` or `(unsigned)bits >> (CHAR_BIT*sizeof bits - 1))` to remove the if

Answer (score 2):

No, you'll need a conditional.

The bitwise shift operators have undefined behavior if you use a negative value on their right.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the number of bits to be shifted is negative, the result is undefined. However, you can experiment with your compiler, it could be that your compiler will shift in the opposite direction.
And of course you could use `?:`, but that's just another way of expressing if-else.