# Elegant way to express shift left OR right in template

Tags: c++

I currently have a template function which, depending on its template parameters A and B, may shift a value either left or right:

```
template <int A, int B> void f(X) {
// ...
if (A >= B)
{
  SetValue(X << (A-B));
}
else // (A < B)
{
  SetValue(X >> (B-A));
}
```

When I instantiate the template for `A<B`, I get a warning for a negative shift right on the (unreachable) first branch, and else I get a warning for a negative shift left on the first branch. Our codebase is warning-free so this isn't acceptable. Is there a concise, readable alternative to these two shift statements?

Similar questions (e.g. [Dynamically shift left OR right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009040/dynamically-shift-left-or-right)) don't have this spurious warning as the shift distance is a runtime variable there.

Comment: If you make the call to f a lot I would pass `A` and `B` as parameters. for each `A` `B` pair the template will make a new function atm.

Comment: ahenderson, perhaps that's the point. Using a template allows you produce specialised functions which don't need to do the checks at run time and for which the shift is by a constant amount.

Comment: @ahenderson: The call is made a lot. But since it's a template, it can be inlined. Each inlined version indeed has 2 constant shift counts. And after dead-code elimination, only one remains. Furthermore, the target CPU is ARM which has very cheap shifts if the distance to shift is constant.

Answer (score 6):

With C++11 or boost.

```
template<int A, int B>
void f_impl(typename std::enable_if<(A >= B)>::type* = 0)
{
   // first case
}

template<int A, int B>
void f_impl(typename std::enable_if<(A < B)>::type* = 0)
{
   // second case
}

template<int A, int B>
void f()
{
   f_impl<A, B>();
}
```

Comment: Convoluted answer to a simple question... just use the absolute value.

Answer (score 4):

Cast the result of (A-B) and (B-A) to unsigned, and additionally mask (bitwise-and) it with `(sizeof(int) - 1)`. This clears the warning for GCC 5.5 and 6.3. For more recent versions of GCC no warning is generated.

```
template <int A, int B> void f(int X) {
  // ...
  if (A >= B)
  {
    SetValue(X << ((unsigned)(A-B) & (sizeof(int) - 1)));
  }
  else // (A < B)
  {
    SetValue(X >> ((unsigned)(B-A) & (sizeof(int) - 1)));
  }
}
```

**Note**
to address the various comments about undefined behaviour: the only sense in which this proposed solution might cause undefined behaviour is by performing a shift of an amount greater than the bit-width of the operand. However, this is guarded by the comparison; assuming that the difference between A and B is a safe shift count, which is implied in the question, then `if (A >= B)` ensures that that only a shift with that amount actually executes. The other branch of the `if` statement is *not* executed and so does not perform a shift and cannot produce undefined behaviour from the shift (although if it were executed, it certainly would do so).

A couple of commenters have made an assertion that the branch which is not executed can still cause undefined behaviour. I am somewhat at a loss as to how such a miscomprehension could occur. Consider the following code:

```
int *a = nullptr;

if (a != nullptr) {
    *a = 4;
}
```

Now, if dereference of a null pointer causes undefined behaviour even when it is not executed, the guard condition becomes useless. This is clearly not the case. The above code is perfectly fine; it assigns `a` a value of `nullptr`, and doesn't then dereference `a`, due to the guard. Although such obvious examples (with the assignment to null immediately followed by a check for null) do not tend to occur in real code, the "guarded dereference" in general is a common idiom. It certainly does not by itself produce undefined behaviour if the pointer checked actually is null; that's why the guard is useful.

Comment: That sounds like a recepe for undefined behavior.  The result of one of these expressions will be a very, very big value, and shifting by more than the number of bits in the object is undefined behavior.

Comment: This doesn't help. I now have a warning for shifting over too many bits, still in unreachable code. (So it's not UB)

Comment: You're at the mercy of the compiler, I suppose. You could try ANDing the A-B result with something (eg 0x1F for 32-bit limit).

Comment: James Kanze, "undefined behavior" only occurs when the code is executed / evaluated.

Comment: @davmac: Actually... no. This is a common confusion, but the compiler may derive optimizations for code that is not executed. So it will depend where you actually perform the cast.

Comment: Matthiew M., I'm sorry but you are just plain wrong. You can't evoke undefined behaviour from code that can never execute. The compiler is broken if it makes assumptions based on code that it cannot be certain will execute. In this case the 'if (A >= B)' condition would guard against the possibility of a negative value being cast to an unsigned type.

Comment: @davmac it's you who are wrong. https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/09/why-undefined-behavior-may-call-never.html

Comment: @v.oddou no. The example in the post you linked _does_ actually execute code which invokes undefined behaviour (specifically, it calls a function via a function pointer which hasn't been initialised). That is different from a program containing code which _would_ invoke undefined behaviour _if it were_ executed (or executed with certain values in certain variables), but which is never actually executed (with those values).

Comment: @davmac oh yes I see. it's the exact reverse case. Then I just take back my `you are wrong`.

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious is to forward to a function taking an 
additional argument:

```
template <bool Cond> struct Discrim {};

template <int A, int B>
void f( Discrim<false> )
{
    SetValue( X, (A - B) );
}

template <int A, int B>
void f( Discrim<true> )
{
    SetValue( X, (B - A) );
}

template <int A, int B>
void f()
{
    f( Discrim< (A < B) >() );
}
```

(Use of such a Discrim class template is one of the simpler
meta-programming techniques.)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in my draughts engine which heavily uses bitboards for its board representation

```
namespace detail {

enum { Left, Right };

template<typename, std::size_t>
struct Shift;

// partial specialization for bitwise shift-left
template<std::size_t N>
struct Shift<Left, N>
{
        template<typename T>
        T operator()(T x) const
        {
                return x << N;
        }
};

// partial specialization for bitwise shift-right
template<std::size_t N>
struct Shift<Right, N>
{
        template<typename T>
        T operator()(T x) const
        {
                return x >> N;
        }
};

} // namespace detail

template<int N>
struct Shift
{
        template<typename T>
        T operator()(T x)
        {            
            return N >= 0 ? detail::Shift<Left, N>()(x) : detail::Shift<Right, -N>()(x);
        }
};

template <int A, int B> 
void f(int x)
{
     SetValue(Shift<A-B>()(x));
}
```

You can do something similar for `ShiftAssign` (`<<=` and `>>=`).

Answer (score 1):

davmac's comment ("use &0x1F") was the right idea, except for the assumed maximum shift width. That was easily fixed:

```
template <int A, int B> void f(X) {
// ...
if (A >= B)
{
  SetValue(X << abs(A-B));
}
else // (A < B)
{
  SetValue(X >> abs(B-A));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new template, and specialise it appropriately, e.g.:

```
template<bool b> int Shift(int i, int a, int b);

template<true> int Shift(int i, int a, int b) { return i << (a-b); }
template<false> int Shift(int i, int a, int b) { return i >> (b-a); }
```

And then invoke it as `Shift<(A >= B)>(X, A, B)`. That should work.

Comment: It does requires passing the `A` and `B` values twice though, which may lead to errors => wrap it! wrap it! :D

Comment: Fair point. Another layer would neaten things up, but I've left that as an exercise for the reader ;)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

```
template <int A, int B> struct whatever {
    static void f() {
        SetValue(X << (A - B));
    }
};

template <int A, int B, bool reversed> helper : whatever<A, B> {
};

template <int A, int B, true> : helper whatever<B, A> {
};

template <int A, int B> do_it : helper<A, B, B < A> {
};

template <int A, int B> void f() {
    return do_it<A, B>::f();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the shift operations in seperate structures and use `std::conditional` in C++11:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename X>
struct ShiftRight
{
    static void shift() { SetValue(X >> (A - B)); }
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename X>
struct ShiftLeft
{
    static void shift() { SetValue(X << (A - B)); }
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename X>
void f()
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<A >= B, ShiftLeft<A, B, X>, ShiftRight<A, B, X>>::type ShiftType;

    ShiftType::shift();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template< int A, int B > void f(X)
{
    std::function< int(int, int) > shift =
        A < B
        ? [](int X, int N) { return X << N; }
        : [](int X, int N) { return X >> N; }

    SetValue( shift( X, std::max(A,B) - std::min(A,B) ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a fairly minor change would simply be to zero out the non-executed shift with a multiply. The compiler can still do all the work at compile time:

```
template <int A, int B> void f(X) {
// ...
if (A >= B)
{
  SetValue(X << ((A < B) * (A-B)));
}
else // (A < B)
{
  SetValue(X >> ((A >= B) * (B-A)));
}
```

I believe a cleaner approach may be to dispatch to a true/false specialized template that knows how to shift the proper direction.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this :-

```
#include <iostream>

template <int A, int B, bool D> class shift
{
};

template <int A, int B> class shift<A, B, false>
{
public:
    static int result(int x) {return x << (B-A);}
};

template <int A, int B> class shift<A, B, true>
{
public:
    static int result(int x) {return x >> (A-B);}
};


template <int A, int B> int f(int x)
{
    return shift<A, B, (A>B)>::result(x);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f<1, 2>(10) << "\n";
    std::cout << f<2, 1>(10) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question : using C++17, it's now easy.

```
template <int A, int B> void f(X) {
if constexpr (A >= B)
// ^^^^^^^^^
{
  SetValue(X << (A-B));
}
else // (A < B)
{
  SetValue(X >> (B-A));
}
```

The branch where the shift is negative will be *discarded*.

Comment: Definitely a good solution! Note that as far as I can tell, GCC 7+ no longer produces any warnings for the original code (compiled with `-Wall`).