# How to remove warnings about negative shift that will never occur beucase of correct flow branching?

Tags: c++, templates

I get some very interesting errors when compiling some code using templates.

The problem is that the compiler doesn't seem to be able to compare numbers. It gives a warning whether one parameter is bigger or smaller.

My minimal example looks like this:

```
template< int shift >
struct Shifter
{
int value;

template< int otherShift >
Shifter< shift > &operator >>=( Shifter< otherShift > &rhs )
{
    if ( shift > otherShift )
    {
        this->value = rhs.value >> (shift - otherShift);
        return *this;
    }
    else
    {
        this->value = rhs.value << (otherShift - shift );
        return *this;
    }
}
};

int main( void )
{
Shifter< 3U > a = { 5 };
Shifter< 2U > b = { 2 };

a >>= b;
b >>= a;

}
```

When compiling I get the following warnings:

`In instantiation of 'Shifter<shift>& Shifter<shift>::operator>>=(Shifter<otherShift>&) [with int otherShift = 2; int shift = 3 ]'
warning: left shift by negative number [enabled by default]
In instantiation of 'Shifter<shift>& Shifter<shift>::operator>>=(Shifter<otherShift>&) [with int otherShift = 3; int shift = 2 ]'
warning: right shift by negative number [enabled by default]`

The warning message is translated from danish, so it might not be verbatim.

The compilers are minGW gcc 4.7.2 on windows as well as iccarm from IAR

I really need this to work using c++03 without boost, so please no enable_if or "just use boost-this-and-that" answers.

BTW my unittests works fine but i'd rather not have warnings when compiling my code.

Comment: What is c++04? You mean c++03?

Comment: I think you meant `=` in place of those `==`s.

Comment: What about making the template parameter `unsigned int` instead of `int`?

Comment: Also `operator >>=` doesn't return anything, among other trivial errors.

Comment: @user657267, I did, but that doesn't change anything ;)

Comment: @Codor, it is in my original code (uint8_t) but in order do keep it simple I stripped away as much as I could.

Comment: You're making the common mistake of thinking that just because the condition of an `if` can be evaluated at compile time, the compiler will not look at the branches anyway. Most compiler warnings aren't that smart; they just look at every line of code and decide whether they apply there, whether the code can actually ever be executed or not.

Comment: Similar if not identical to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627818/elegant-way-to-express-shift-left-or-right-in-template)

Comment: @MSalters, You seem to be correct; my bad.
However, I do think this question got the better and more elegant answers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the compiler doesn't check the if clause and thus can not know, whether you perform a negative shift.

You can avoid this by using the absolute function:

```
#include <cstdlib>

// ...

template< int otherShift >
Shifter< shift > &operator >>=( Shifter< otherShift > &rhs )
{
    if ( shift > otherShift )
    {
        this->value = rhs.value >> abs(shift - otherShift);
        return *this;
    }
    else
    {
        this->value = rhs.value << abs(otherShift - shift );
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: This sure seems to fix the problem, but why doesn't the compiler check the if clause?

Comment: Because if clauses are evaluated at runtime. Although in this case it is easy to see how they will evaluate at other cases it's not and might be totally depending on runtime behavior.

Comment: @Paul - Because it does not have to. Optimization is an optional step. The compiler may do, or may not. Even so, whatever it chooses, at some point of time your code contains the negative-shift, so the compiler may, or may not emit a warning. The compiler also may, or may not optimize-out the if clause at all. That's optinal too. The compiler **is allowed to leave** the never-executable branch in your code. Never rely too much on something being optimized out, or you may get badly suprised.

Comment: @Paul - Also, that's just a warning. You can always supress one or two warnings with some `#pragma`. The set of rules that generate warnings is never perfect. That's why that's warning not hard error. You may know better here, and if you are sure that the code is OK, then just supress the warnings for these few lines. That's what the suppression is for!

Comment: It seems that OP wants the reverse shifting with negative numbers whereas your solution always shift on the same side.

Comment: @hildensia: Jarod42 made a good point! To be complete, the code here should look like `if(..) val = .. >> abs(x); else val = .. << abs(x);`.

Answer (score 1):

even if `shift` and `otherShift` are template parameter in:

```
if (shift > otherShift) {
    this->value = rhs.value >> (shift - otherShift);
    return *this;
} else {
    this->value = rhs.value << (otherShift - shift );
    return *this;
}
```

compiler has to evaluate all branches (and so the branch should be valid).
So even you ensure yo call the correct shift according to sign of (`shift - otherShift`), the other (dead) branch produces warning.

You may use SFINAE:

```
template< int otherShift >
typename std::enable_if<(shift > otherShift), Shifter<shift> >::type
&operator >>=( Shifter< otherShift > &rhs )
{
    this->value = rhs.value >> (shift - otherShift);
    return *this;
}

template< int otherShift >
typename std::enable_if<(shift <= otherShift), Shifter<shift> >::type
&operator >>=( Shifter< otherShift > &rhs )
{
    this->value = rhs.value << (otherShift - shift );
    return *this;
}
```

With C++03 you may define your own `enable_if`:

```
template<bool Cond, class T = void> struct enable_if {};
template<class T> struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

Comment: You've beaten me by a few minutes with those :) I was just about to write the same thing about explicitely meta'izing the `if` check and branching. However as usual I forgot about something in std and started digging in boost::mpl again.. I think you could add a bit more info than just "use SFINAE", as the `sfinae<->enable_if` is not really clear to those not used to these tricks.

Comment: You guys really should read the entire question :)
But thanks for adding the "modern" approach for others.

Comment: @Paul: you may write easily your own `enable_if` (code provided).